# MySQL query - 2 sets of conditions

Tags: mysql, cakephp, logical-operators

I've been thinking about this for too long, and have got myself confused!  I'm trying to come up with a MySQL query in CakePHP, for the following scenario:

Each record has 2 dates; for the sake of simplicity I'll call them F & I. These determine the quality of the data, as follows:

- Bad data - F & I are both null
- Good data - F & I are both non-null and represent dates within the past 3 months
  'In between' data - everything else

The first 2 are easy enough:

Red:

```
$conditions['AND'] = array('F' => null, 'I' => null);
```

Green:

```
$conditions['AND'] = array(
     'F >=' => Three months ago,
     'I >=' => Three months ago
)
```

But I'm having trouble with the third option. I've tried a few things, and I know it's something like:

```
$conditions['NOT'] = array(
     'AND' => array(
         'F >=' => Three months ago,
         'I >=' => Three months ago
     ),
     'AND' => array(
          'F' => null,
          'I' => null
     )
)
```

but obviously that's not going to work because it has two different values for 'AND'.

Comment: It will much clear if you place few data with question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a problem in your boolean logic.  If you want F & I to represent dates within the past three months, then you're ruling out any entries where F >= three months OR I >= three months.

It'd be less confusing to use De Morgan’s law on your boolean logic -- `NOT (F >= three months OR I >= three months)` is the same as `F < three months AND I < three months`.  Therefore, for the third rule, your conditions array would look like:

`array('conditions' => array('AND' => array('F <' => three months, 'I <' => three months)));`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up re-writing it in the way you suggested, and got there eventually!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about it, but try this:

```
$conditions['AND'] = array(
    'NOT' => array(
        'AND' => array(
            'F >=' => Three months ago,
            'I >=' => Three months ago
         )
     ),
     'NOT' => array(
         'AND' => array(
             'F' => null,
             'I' => null
         )
     )
)
```

First you negate each condition and the outer `'AND'` is needed because you want both conditions not to be true.

Comment: Thank you - I tried that though, and it missed some of the results, for some reason.  But it got me a bit closer!